# Opening drawer of empty optical drive

Tags: optical-drive, eject

Is there a command to tell an external optical drive to open that still works when there's no disk in it?

It has a button on the drawer, but it's vary tiny, and it requires a push in the opposite direction of opening.  It's so thin that I have to pick it up off the table to push it, and I have to push hard enough and not too hard.  And if I'm not fast enough, the slight pressure is enough to prevent opening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of an eject button on the keyboard, you may have to resort to Terminal…

```
/usr/bin/drutil eject
```

Comment: Older laptop does have an eject button (and an internal drive that can't eject).  With this drive plugged in, the eject button would not open the tray if empty.  the shell command does work on this no-drive MacBook.

Comment: If you have two drives & need differentiation,  https://ss64.com/osx/drutil.html gives finer control